# How to refer to the a properties accessor and mutator (getter/setter)

Tags: c#, properties

I am wondering if there is a high performant way to refer to a properties getter or setter. For example, how would I fill in the details for the second example class below

```
public class Example
{
    public Example()
    {
        Action<int> setter = SetX;
        Func<int> getter = GetX;
    }
    public int GetX() { return 0; }
    public void SetX(int value){}
}

public class Example2
{
    public Example2()
    {
        Action<int> setter = ...;
        Func<int> getter = ...;
    }
    public int X
    {
        get{ return 0; }
        set{}
    }
}
```

I know I could create lamdas myself like so: `Action<int> setter = x => X = x` . However one of the reasons I wish to do this is to compare the references themselves in other parts of the application. So I actually wish to use the references to identify the particular property.

For example, I would want this to succeed :

```
var example = new Example();
Func<int> something = example.GetX;
Func<int> somethingElse = example.GetX;
bool equality = something.Equals(somethingElse);
```

Only with using properties.

I imagine this could be accomplished with reflection, however it would be likely for many of these operations to occur 30 times a second or so throughout my application, so I am hesitant to use a solution like that rather then just declaring GetX and SetX methods, even though that seems clumsy.

The end goal is to create a syntaticly simple way to both set a field, and inform those who have been linked up that it has been set, and to avoid the use of strings to accomplish it. Here's an example not using Properties, however the linkages would be made with additional abstractions

```
public class Example
{
    public event Action<Delegate> Change;

    int x = 0;
    public int GetX() { return x; }
    public void SetX(int value) 
    {
        SetField(ref x, value, GetX);
    }

    protected void SetField<T>(ref T t, T value, Func<T> getter)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(getter(), value))
        {
            t = value;
            if(Change != null)
                Change(getter);
        }
    }
}

var example = new Example();
example.Change += getter =>
{
    Func<int> getX = example.GetX;
    if (getter.Equals(getX)) 
    {
        this.Log("x changed to: " + getX());
    }
};

example.SetX(5); // change is logged
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the references"? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JonSkeet If he has methods (as in the first example) he can use the method identifier without invoking it to get a delegate that refers to that method.  He would like to (in example 2) to get a delegate that refers to the set and/or get actions of a property.  As far as I know, there is no way of doing this.

Comment: @Servy: But how would that help? That's what isn't clear at the moment. Using a method group conversion twice for the same instance will still create two distinct (but equal) delegate instances. p.s.w.g.'s answer *may* be what's wanted here, but the requirements just aren't clear enough for me to say...

Comment: @JonSkeet I added an example of what I meant, If need be I can go into further detail of the actual problem I'm trying to solve elegantly, but I think that may be a different question if this turns out to not be possible.

Comment: @MikeMcFarland: Using `==` between two delegate instances is probably the wrong approach. Using `Equals` would be more appropriate. Do you *really* need to compare just the references?

Comment: @JonSkeet I should have been explain more about why originally, does my last edit suffice? Who knows, maybe there's another way just as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think reflection is the only way to do this:

```
public Example2()
{
    var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty("X");
    Action<int> setter = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), this, prop.GetSetMethod());
    Func<int> getter = (Func<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>), this, prop.GetGetMethod());
}
```

But as you said, reflection is not particularly fast. You could define internal getters / setters as methods and bind to those, but that's not exactly what you were asking for either:

```
public Example2()
{
    Action<int> setter = this.GetX;
    Func<int> getter = this.SetX;
}

private int GetX() { return 0; }
private void SetX(int value) { }

public int X 
{
    get { return GetX(); } 
    set { SetX(value); } 
}
```

Comment: thanks for showing me how to do it with reflection, I may end up testing out if performance really does suffer using it, was just hoping there was a feature I didn't know about already. Being able to call the GetGetMethod() without reflection would be perfect :)

Comment: Actually, in the last example, it is illegal to introduce a property `X` when the class alreay has methods with the exact names `get_X` and `set_X` with the given signatures. But rename the methods to `GetX` and `SetX`, for example.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I never knew that it would complain about that--I figured it would munge the internal names to `get_X_1` or something like that. Thanks for the info.